# Find the lowest unoccupied space in a range of numbers

Tags: python, sorting

Say I generate a list from 0 - 10:

```
range(10)
```

Then I have a list of dictionaries, that look something like this:

```
item = [{'position': 0}, {'position': 4}]
```

How can I get the lowest number that is in the range that is not in `position`? For example, if I ask it for the next available position, it should return 1; and, having added it to the list, then 2, etc, until it hits 4, in which case it should return 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> item = [{'position': 0}, {'position': 4}]
>>> min(set(range(10)) - set(x['position'] for x in item))
1
```

You find all position values `(x['position'] for x in item))`,
convert this list to set, substract it from the set of all numbers from 0 to maximum, 
and then find minimum in the resulting set.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I tried something like this, but without sets, and it didn't work out that great. Accepting in ~3 mins.